# Can I move an imported camera track in Maya without manually changing 500+ keyframes?

Tags: animation, 3d, tracking, maya, nuke

I have a match-moved camera track from Nuke but it's in the wrong place in my scene/environment, is it possible to select the camera's track and manipulate it without having to manually edit the 501 keyframes that make up its movement?

Would it be easier to move the whole rest of the scene, or is there an option I missed when creating the track that would orient/position it correctly?

Comment: I am having the same problem .. I have tried to bake the camera but it didn't worked. once I hit play the camera just stay stooped.

Answer (score 2):

Select your camera, locators (if exported), and anything else from Nuke. Group them all together with <kbd>ctrl+g</kbd> and modify that group as a whole.

You can scale uniformly (but not independent axes), rotate, and translate.

Often one trick is to snap the pivot point of the group to a specific reference point (hold down <kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd> then drag to the reference point, and then snap the group to the corresponding point in your scene (just hold <kbd>v</kbd> while dragging). Then rotate and scale to align the rest of the group.

When finished, you can simply unparent anything not animated with <kbd>shift+p</kbd>, but animated objects like your camera will need to be baked:

To bake the camera, duplicate it, unparent it, then parent-constrain it to the camera (Animation menu > Constrain > Parent Constraint). Then bake the keyframes (Edit > Keys > Bake Simulation) and you can then delete the constraint and the original camera.

Comment: There are options to orient/position the track correctly when solving in Nuke, but it would be beyond the scope of one question to answer that as well. If you ask it separately I'll answer it.

Answer (score 0):

My Maya is a bit rusty, but I know in SoftImage you can make a nested group and then animate or manipulate that group.  Things then animate as the sum total of the nested rotations and translations.  I'm pretty sure that Maya has a similar feature, but I haven't used it in about 10 years.  If you nest the animated camera in such a group, it should then just be a matter of moving that group to reposition the camera entirely.

Additionally, you might also be able to try altering the anchor point position and orientation rather than the actual animated position parameters, though if you aren't careful this can throw off any rotations if you don't have independent anchor and center points or if there are any rotations around the anchor point output by the motion tracking.